# intercom-rails: set some custom data attribute specific in action

Tags: ruby-on-rails, intercom

I want to set custom data attribute with intercom-rails gem. In `UserController#sign_up` I have `intercom_custom_data.user[:sign_up] = true` but the variable is not created. I try in other controller (`TruckController#edit`) and if it is created.

**user_controller.rb**

```
class UserController < ApplicationController                                                                                                                                                                                                               
  skip_before_filter :check_admin
  skip_before_filter :authenticate_user!, except: [:recovery]
  skip_before_filter :verify_authenticity_token
    
  def sign_up
    ...
    if user.save
      puts current_user.inspect 
      # <User id: 11, username: "user", email: "user@email.com", encrypted_password: "aebvcbb5c..."
      intercom_custom_data.user[:sign_up] = true
    end
  end
end
```

**truck_controller.rb**

```
TruckController < ApplicationController
  def index
    puts current_user.inspect 
    # <User id: 11, username: "user", email: "user@email.com", encrypted_password: "aebvcbb5c..."
    intercom_custom_data.user[:sign_up] = true
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I would add a field to my User model, **signed_up**, so you can change it in whatever way you want.

Now, go to your intercom.rb config file in config/initializers, and add a custom data field to your User model:

```
IntercomRails.config do |config|
  ...
  config.user.model = Proc.new { YourUserModelClass }

  config.user.custom_data = {
    :sign_up=> Proc.new { |user| user.signed_up }
  }
  ...
end
```

You should see the field in Intercom after.